# Is this the correct way to use condition variables?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

Are there any risks with the code below? Can someone please explain why I have to use `pthread_cond_broadcast` instead of `pthread_cond_signal` in my case please?

```
#include <pthread.h>

unsigned int target_id;
pthread_mutex_t my_mytex;
pthread_cond_t my_cond;

void *print_item_(void *ar)
{
    int id = *((unsigned int*)ar);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&my_mytex);

    while (id != target_id)
        pthread_cond_wait(&my_cond, &my_mytex);

    printf("%u\n", id);
    target_id++;
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&my_cond);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&my_mytex);
    free(ar);
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t *threads;
    unsigned int *var;
    int i;

    target_id = 1;
    pthread_mutex_init(&my_mytex, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&my_cond, NULL);

    threads = (pthread_t*)malloc(sizeof(pthread_t)*50);

    for(i = 1; i < 50; i++)
    {
        var = (unsigned int*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned int));
        var[0] = i+1;

        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, print_item_, (void*)var);
    }

    var = (unsigned int*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned int));
    var[0] = 1;

    pthread_create(&threads[0], NULL, print_item_, (void*)var);

    for(i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);

    free(threads);
}
```

Comment: @4386427 Thanks for the help! I mean why pthread_cond_wait in my case doesn't work.

Comment: @4386427 Yes, if I do this the program pauses forever. Why?

Comment: You have tons of memory leaks. You are not `free`ing `malloc`ated vars...

Comment: Because no one unlock threads pending on conditional value....

Comment: @LPs Thanks a lot, fixed. Do you have any other advice please?

Comment: @4386427 My apologies, I made a typo. I meant signal vs broadcast.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense :-) Signal only releases one thread. If that thread doesn't have the next target_id, you have a deadlock. Broadcast releases all threads so the thread with correct target_id will execute. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_cond_broadcast.html

Comment: @4386427 Thanks a lot and sorry for the mistake!

Comment: BTW - sinse you had a specific code question, SO is ok for your question. For code reviews you could consider http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Right now this code would be closed over on CR as "unclear".  Also, if you post it over there you should not be asking for an explanation of the code.

Comment: If this really is C code to be compiled by a C compiler, you might just want to remove all those useless casts. This excludes the 1st one in the thread function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're using condition variables there is correct.

The reason you need to use `pthread_cond_broadcast()` is that in your design, you might have multiple threads waiting on the condition variable where only a particular one of them will be ready to proceed if the condition is signalled. This means you need to use `pthread_cond_broadcast()` to wake them *all* up, which ensures that the single thread that can proceed will be woken.

`pthread_cond_signal()` is an optimisation - it wakes one of the waiting threads, but it isn't specified which one, so it's only applicable for situations where *any* of the waiting threads will be able to proceed if woken.

By the way, nothing is gained by special-casing thread 1 (`i == 0`) in the loop that calls `pthread_create()`.